# What is the relation of DBD::Mysql to ODBC?

Tags: mysql, perl, odbc, dbi, cpan

In http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/DBD-mysql/DBD/mysql.pm.html there are certain references to ODBC but afaik DBD::mysql is "parallel" in the connection stack to DBD::ODBC.

Does anyone know why is ODBC mentioned there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DBD::mysql`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql) supports the ODBC style DSNs like `DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost`.
It contains some functions to parse these DSNs.

Comment: So does that mean it will use ODBC to connect to the database or only parsing the dsn and then using its own native connection to MySQL?

Comment: @szabgab: I mean syntax of the connection string. See also search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.615/DBI.pm#connect